# Forwarding serial output from a Nano to Uno that's used as the ISP

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-nano, isp

I'm trying to program a Nano by using an Uno as the ISP. So far, I've followed along with the example project for getting the Uno running as the ISP on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP.

After a bit of tinkering, it works, but the serial monitor won't work correctly. I'm uploading a super simple program that delays for 500 ms and prints to the log.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("test");
  delay(500);
}
```

I've wired the TX pin on the Nano to the RX pin on the uno. The monitor updates every 500 ms as expected after doing so, but displays ��� instead of the word test. When I tried wiring TX -> TX, the serial monitor does not update. Does anyone have any insight what's missing here?

Comment: You can't really connect an ordinary Arduino's serial pins to both another device and the on-board USB serial converter at the same time.  You'd probably do best to use a separate USB serial converter for the target, otherwise you need to use software serial (or better a chip with a 2nd hardware port) and add some sort of selectable pass-through mode to your ISP sketch.  Possible, but not easy, try using the separate converter instead.

Comment: @ChrisStratton gotcha, thank's for the explanation. I tried to use the mini usb to connect the nano, but my computer doesn't seem to recognize it. It was still fun to learn about ISPs though

Comment: @ChrisStratton. Please, post your comment as an answer to close this question.

Comment: Can you try by writing on the uno a program to set the TX and RX pins as inputs? Just something like `void setup() { pinMode(0, INPUT); pinMode(1, INPUT); } void loop() {}`, then repeat again the test (I think you'll have to connect the nano TX to TX and nano RX to RX)

Answer (score 1):

As [Chris Stratton](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/612/chris-stratton) suggests in his comment above:

> You can't really connect an ordinary Arduino's serial pins to both another device and the on-board USB serial converter at the same time.

To solve your serial monitor problem use a separate USB serial converter and connect that to your Arduino Nano.

If you don't have access to a dedicated USB serial converter you could use [software serial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) on the Arduino Nano. This allows you to connect the Arduino Uno Rx pin to the software serial Tx pin. You will also need to program the Arduino Uno with a program that re-transmits the data it receives back out to the PC serial monitor.